# Difference between ./bin/webpack and rails assets:precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Starting with RAILS 6 - there are two ways to compile the assets (javascript) when running in DEVELOPMENT mode.

-> **./bin/webpack**

-> **rails assets:precompile**

But what is the difference ?

Answer (score 3):

`rails assets:precompile` compiles all types of assets, including anything managed by sprockets, ie `app/assets/*` (CSS, images, fonts, etc). It *also* compiles Webpack-managed assets.

`./bin/webpack` only compiles your Webpack-managed assets (typically JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

For fun, in a second terminal, run this from the root of your app:

```
$ bin/webpack-dev-server
```

that will show you any issues or success compiling webpack assets within `app/javascript/`

This post was helpful to understand the difference between asset pipeline and webpacker in Rails 6: https://blog.capsens.eu/how-to-write-javascript-in-rails-6-webpacker-yarn-and-sprockets-cdf990387463